# Ionic 2 not firing lifycycle event on back

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a view with a very simple navbar:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

The page is loaded through a `push`:

```
    this.navCtrl.push(ClientGenericPage, {
        client: data
      }, { animation: 'ios-transition' });
    }
```

and the view displays a "back" button as expected even though it is not coded since the page is pushed on top of the stack.

The issue arises when I click the back button.  No lifecycle events fire, and thus my `Observables` are not `unsubscribed`.

```
  // Not fired
  ionViewDidLeave() {
    console.log("left details page")
    this.client_obs.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Is there any lifecycle event that fires on going back or some other way to know I am navigating away?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ionViewDidEnter` or `ionViewDidLoad` for getting the work done on returning to the page after clicking the back button after `push`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue using both the `ionViewDidLeave` and the `ionViewWillUnload` lifecycle hooks.